# Rviz visualization for the radar

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
i am new to ROS and i would like to visualize my radar data on rviz.
My radar.msg is made in this way :

```
uint8 id
 
float32 distance_sd_m

float32 angle_sd_deg

float32 velocity_sd_m__s

float32 distance_m

float32 angle_deg

float32 velocity_m__s

float32 width_m

float32 length_m
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271146/rviz-visualization-for-the-radar/) by [stitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/31952/stitch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know there is no RViz plugin for this type of sensor. In my work I've regularly used the [marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) message type to visualise complex information that isn't currently supported. Using this type you can visualise any 3D color mesh data you can generate. It's a bit tricky if you're new to ROS but I can post some code examples if you're using C++.

Here is an example code segment that creates a marker mesh message, you'll then need to publish this message to a topic to see it in RVIZ. Once the message has been created and setup you're basically adding a color value then three vertices for each triangle, each triangle can be a different color (in my example they're all the same).

This example uses a vector of Eigen::Vector3f to represent the vertices and a vector of custom triangle structures, you can replace this with anything you wish for your own project.

```
// create Mesh message
visualization_msgs::Marker meshMarker;

// setup Triangle_List marker message
meshMarker.header.frame_id = "Coordinate_frame_id";
meshMarker.header.stamp = ros::Time();
meshMarker.ns = "custom_mesh";
meshMarker.id = 0;
meshMarker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::TRIANGLE_LIST;
meshMarker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
meshMarker.pose.position.x = 0;
meshMarker.pose.position.y = 0;
meshMarker.pose.position.z = 0;
meshMarker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
meshMarker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
meshMarker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
meshMarker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
meshMarker.scale.x = 1;
meshMarker.scale.y = 1;
meshMarker.scale.z = 1;
meshMarker.color.a = 1.0;

// create temp vertex and color objects.
geometry_msgs::Point    vertex;
std_msgs::ColorRGBA meshColor;

// add triangles
for (int f=0; f<triangles.size(); ++f)
{
    meshColor.r = 1.0;
    meshColor.g = 0.5;
    meshColor.b = 0.0;

    meshMarker.colors.push_back(meshColor);

    // add triangle to mesh
    vertex.x = vertices[triangles[f].v1][0];
    vertex.y = vertices[triangles[f].v1][1];
    vertex.z = vertices[triangles[f].v1][2];
    meshMarker.points.push_back(vertex);

    vertex.x = vertices[triangles[f].v2][0];
    vertex.y = vertices[triangles[f].v2][1];
    vertex.z = vertices[triangles[f].v2][2];
    meshMarker.points.push_back(vertex);

    vertex.x = vertices[triangles[f].v3][0];
    vertex.y = vertices[triangles[f].v3][1];
    vertex.z = vertices[triangles[f].v3][2];
    meshMarker.points.push_back(vertex);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/31952/stitch/) on 2017-09-21**:
Yes I am using C++.
I had heard of the markers but I couldn't get to a solution.
Thank you very much, your codes would be a great help!

**Comment by [stitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/31952/stitch/) on 2017-09-26**:
Can you please post those examples?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-09-26**:
I've just added it to my original post. Let me know if you have any questions getting this going.

**Comment by [stitch](https://answers.ros.org/users/31952/stitch/) on 2017-09-26**:
This is a special type of marker(similar to http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A Basic Shapes) ...but still i can't see how to represent the radar data through it

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-09-26**:
You're right it is one of the basic marker types in rviz.
The beauty of this message type is you write nodes to generate them for all different types of information.
Work out how you want the radar information displayed in rviz, then write a node to convert the radar message to a mesh.